# Backbutton PHONEGAP

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova

Pessoal me ajuda nesta aqui...

Estou querendo fazer a função de `backbutton`, porem já tentei algumas forma e todas fazem com que o aplicativo saia. No emulate ja esta funcionando.

Faço seguinte:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyBack, false);
}

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReadyBack() {
    // Register the event listener
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}

// Handle the back button
//
function onBackKeyDown() {
    window.history.back();
    //alert("entro aqui");
}
```

Como fazer para não sair da aplicação ?

Comment: da uma olhada nisso veja se te ajuda http://pt.androids.help/q3977

Comment: Nem me ajudou.. To sofrendo para conseguir isto.

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Você não precisa criar um function onload. Se o cordova estiver instalado corretamente, tente o seguinte:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyBack, false);

function onDeviceReadyBack() {
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', onBackKeyDown, false);
}

function onBackKeyDown() {
    try {
        alert("Executou aqui!");
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

É exatamente assim que uso em meus projetos. Se mesmo assim o aplicativo fechar sem executar o método de BackButton, quer dizer que existe algum problema com o loading do Cordova.

Veja se existe algum erro sobre o não carregamento ou carregamento incorreto do Cordova em seu console e lembre-se de declarar o cordova.js.

Espero que ajude. :)

Comment: Na verdade meu problema foi porque eu utilizava o Framework e ele estava gerenciando isto, quando localizei eu resolvi meu problema.